# The adverb 'already' and the past simple

Tags: adverbs, british-english

What adverb can I use in sentence which is in the past simple when I cannot use the adverb *already*? I mean, of course British English. What do different adverbs  have the same meaning as the adverb *already*?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Any examples of what you wish to say? Maybe **by then** or **by that time** or maybe even "yet"?

Comment: What do you mean, "*cannot* use the adverb *already*"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I mean this [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/already?q=already).

Comment: That link does not help me understand your use of the word **cannot**.  Are you saying that someone has given you an exercise where you must find an *alternative* for **already**? Or are you saying that you believe **already** would be ungrammatical with the past simple?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm sorry. I used the wrong word. I meant we **should not**. No, I'm not but I would like to know what to use in British English.

Comment: If you mean that it would be ungrammatical to use **already** with the past tense, that is not quite correct. You can do so.  Some native speakers would say "I have already been there" while others would say "I already went there".  or *I have already done it* vs. *I already did it*.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using ***already*** in any tense. At all. So I'm not sure what the 'scenario' behind this question is.

However, you can always look up *already* [in a thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/already) and you get some alternatives. As usual for thesaurus alternatives, they won't all work in every case where you might use *already*, but they do convey some similar sense. For example ***by that time*** means that whatever it was, was done before that time (if not necessarily long before***. ***Previously*** means the action was done at some preceding time. There are quite a lot to choose from.

The comments that were posted soon after the question **have already**<sup>1</sup> covered some of this ground, but without clarification there's not much more I can do.

---

<sup>1</sup>: see what I did there?